# Understanding the base step in inductive proof that Lucas number are the sum of consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Define the Lucas numbers to be

$$l_n = l_{n-1} + l_{n-2} $$

if $n \ge 2$ with initial conditions $l_0 = 2$ and $l_1= 1$.

I "proved" by induction that $l_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n+1}$ for $n \ge 1$ (by $f_n$ I mean the n'th Fibonacci number) but never used the initial condition $l_0 = 2$, so I would like for someone to point out the flaw.

**Proof:**  Instead of using regular induction, let's use strong induction.  The base case is obvious $l_1$ is obvious.  Now suppose the equation holds for $1 \le n$ for some $n$.   Using the inductive hypothesis and the definition of fibonacci numbers

$$l_{n+1} = l_{n} + l_{n-1} = f_{n-1} + f_{n+1} + f_{n-2} + f_{n} = f_n + f_{n+2}$$

I can't find out the flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: Your inductive step fails for $n = 1$ if you don't know anything about $l_0$.

Answer (score 2):

In the induction step for $\,n = 1\,$ you implicitly use $\,l_0 = f_{-1}\! + f_{1}\, (= 1 + 1).\, $ The induction proof essentially shows that if $\:l_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n+1}\,$ holds true for two successive values $\, n = k,\, k\!+\!1,\:$ then it remains true for all $\,n \ge k.$

Equivalently, by *linearity*, $\ g_n = f_{n-1}\!+f_{n+1}\!-l_n\ $ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence (being a sum of solutions) but has initial conditions $\:g_0\! = 0,\,\ g_1\! = 0,\:$ thus $\:g_n\! = 0\,$ by an obvious induction, using the Fibonacci recurrence (this is  the simple  the *uniqueness theorem* for such recurrences).

As I [often emphasize,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities) uniqueness theorems provide powerful tools for proving equalities.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/247759/242). $\ \ $